# Unable to fetch users and groups using node js activedirectory

Tags: node.js, active-directory

I am using [node js activedirectory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory) module for AD authentication and fetching users & groups. Able to authenticate successfully but unable to get users & groups using .findUser(), .findUsers(), .findGroups() methods. I've added few users and a group using ADSI editor in windows 10. Any clue what could be going wrong?

Screenshot of ADSI editor :

[image: ADSI Screenshot]

My Code :

```
    var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var config = { url: 'ldap://192.168.2.59',
    baseDN: 'cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal',
    username: 'cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal',
    password: '123456' };


var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);

var username = 'cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal';
var password = '123456';

ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }

    if (auth) {
        console.log('Authenticated!');
        ad.findUser({
            dn : "cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal"
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
                return;
            }

            if (! user) console.log('User: not found.');
            else console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
        });

    }
    else {
        console.log('Authentication failed!');
    }
});
```

Output :

Authenticated!
User: not found.

UPDATE :

I can confirm that I've just one domain i.e ec2

Output of getRootDSE() is :

```
getRootDSE: {"dn":"","forestFunctionality":"2","domainControllerFunctionality":"7","supportedSASLMechanisms":["GSSAPI","GSS-SPNEGO","EXTERNAL","DIGEST-MD5"],"supportedLDAPVersion":["3","2"],"supportedLDAPPolicies":["MaxPoolThreads","MaxPercentDirSyncRequests","MaxDatagramRecv","MaxReceiveBuffer","InitRecvTimeout","MaxConnections","MaxConnIdleTime","MaxPageSize","MaxBatchReturnMessages","MaxQueryDuration","MaxDirSyncDuration","MaxTempTableSize","MaxResultSetSize","MinResultSets","MaxResultSetsPerConn","MaxNotificationPerConn","MaxValRange","MaxValRangeTransitive","ThreadMemoryLimit","SystemMemoryLimitPercent"],"supportedControl":["1.2.840.113556.1.4.319","1.2.840.113556.1.4.801","1.2.840.113556.1.4.473","1.2.840.113556.1.4.528","1.2.840.113556.1.4.417","1.2.840.113556.1.4.619","1.2.840.113556.1.4.841","1.2.840.113556.1.4.529","1.2.840.113556.1.4.805","1.2.840.113556.1.4.521","1.2.840.113556.1.4.970","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1338","1.2.840.113556.1.4.474","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1339","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1340","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1413","2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.9","2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.10","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1504","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1852","1.2.840.113556.1.4.802","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1907","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1948","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1974","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1341","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2026","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2064","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2065","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2066","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2090","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2205","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2204","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2206","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2211","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2239","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2255","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2256","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2309","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2330","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2354"],"supportedCapabilities":["1.2.840.113556.1.4.1851","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1670","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1791","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1935","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2080","1.2.840.113556.1.4.2237","1.2.840.113556.1.4.1880"],"subschemaSubentry":"CN=Aggregate,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,CN={FE444AB2-1728-4C00-BCF6-12DE33BA1FAC}","serverName":"CN=DESKTOP-K4GOMAF$localhost,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,CN={FE444AB2-1728-4C00-BCF6-12DE33BA1FAC}","schemaNamingContext":"CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,CN={FE444AB2-1728-4C00-BCF6-12DE33BA1FAC}","namingContexts":["CN=Configuration,CN={FE444AB2-1728-4C00-BCF6-12DE33BA1FAC}","CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,CN={FE444AB2-1728-4C00-BCF6-12DE33BA1FAC}","CN=admin,DC=ec2,DC=internal"],"isSynchronized":"TRUE","highestCommittedUSN":"12502","dsServiceName":"CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DESKTOP-K4GOMAF$localhost,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,CN={FE444AB2-1728-4C00-BCF6-12DE33BA1FAC}","dnsHostName":"DESKTOP-K4GOMAF","currentTime":"20191204081058.0Z","configurationNamingContext":"CN=Configuration,CN={FE444AB2-1728-4C00-BCF6-12DE33BA1FAC}"}
```

I am wondering why dn is empty string in the above output.

UPDATE : 
After executing ad.find() method, I got below output and now I am surprised why its returning empty users array!! Though I am able to authenticate correctly for user : cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal

ad.find() Output :

```
{ groups: [],
  users: [],
  other: [ { dn: 'CN=admin,DC=ec2,DC=internal' } ] }
```

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me why it wouldn't find it. However I do know that the `activedirectory` project hasn't been touched in years. But someone else forked it and is currently maintaining it under the name [`activedirectory2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2). You could try that package instead and see if you get different results.

Comment: Thank you @GabrielLuci for your kind response. I've even tried activedirectory2 and unfortunately its giving me the same output. 

Did I miss out any thing while creating group and users in ADSI? Or the above screenshot showing the users and group is perfect?

Answer (score 1):

This is my best guess: [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2#findUser) show that you just give it a string, not an object. So maybe try that:

```
ad.findUser("cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal", function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }

    if (! user) console.log('User: not found.');
    else console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
});
```

*Update:* Looking at your logs, it's odd that authentication succeeded for that user, but searching for it failed. The only time I would expect to see that is if you have two domains with a trust between them (either in the same forest or not).

For example, if you have an `EC1` domain, you can authenticate to `EC1` with an account from `EC2`, but you wouldn't be able to find that account if you search `EC1`.

Did you setup two domains?

So I would be curious if the domain you are connecting to is actually `EC2`. You can [query the RootDSE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2#getRootDSE) to find out, like this:

```js
ad.getRootDSE(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }

  console.log('getRootDSE: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Then look at the `defaultNamingContext` property of that object and see if it matches `dc=ec2,dc=internal`.

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel, the first parameter can be an object or a string. However, I've tried both ways still I am not able to retrieve user.

Comment: Looking at [the source code for `findUser`](https://github.com/jsumners/node-activedirectory/blob/jsumners/lib/activedirectory.js#L840), I don't think it can be an object. It will enter the `if (typeof username === 'function')`, and set `_username = opts`, but I don't see anywhere that it treats `_username` as an object.

Comment: There are several `log.trace` lines in the code. If you can enable the [`logging` option](https://github.com/jsumners/node-activedirectory#optional-parameters--extended-functionality), you might be able to get more info about what's going wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include something you can try.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, I've updated my question with the output of getRootDSE()

Comment: Updated the question with ad.find() output

Comment: Yeah, that's odd. Seems like something is off with the configuration of your domain. But that's a bit beyond me. It seems like it depends on if you're using AD DS or AD LDS. [This says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/c1ad47fb-e4a1-4240-a749-b8f07ee0ae91) how you can set the `defaultNamingContext` for AD LDS. You might get better help with configuring the domain on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com). At this point, I don't think it's an issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Gabriel for suggesting about the log trace option. I passed DN string as a parameter for findUser() method but still the same result. Following is the log :

```
{"name":"ldapApp","hostname":"DESKTOP-K4GOMAF","pid":15828,"level":30,"msg":"Using username/password (cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal/********) to bind to ActiveDirectory (ldap://192.168.2.59).","time":"2019-12-03T06:09:33.170Z","v":0}
{"name":"ldapApp","hostname":"DESKTOP-K4GOMAF","pid":15828,"level":30,"msg":"Referrals are disabled","time":"2019-12-03T06:09:33.172Z","v":0}
{"name":"ldapApp","hostname":"DESKTOP-K4GOMAF","pid":15828,"level":30,"msg":"Default user attributes: [\"dn\",\"userPrincipalName\",\"sAMAccountName\",\"mail\",\"lockoutTime\",\"whenCreated\",\"pwdLastSet\",\"userAccountControl\",\"employeeID\",\"sn\",\"givenName\",\"initials\",\"cn\",\"displayName\",\"comment\",\"description\"]","time":"2019-12-03T06:09:33.173Z","v":0}
{"name":"ldapApp","hostname":"DESKTOP-K4GOMAF","pid":15828,"level":30,"msg":"Default group attributes: [\"dn\",\"cn\",\"description\"]","time":"2019-12-03T06:09:33.173Z","v":0}
{"name":"ldapApp","hostname":"DESKTOP-K4GOMAF","pid":15828,"level":30,"msg":"Authentication succeeded for \"ldap://192.168.2.59\" as \"cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal\" (password: \"********\")","time":"2019-12-03T06:09:33.191Z","v":0}
Authenticated!
{"name":"ldapApp","hostname":"DESKTOP-K4GOMAF","pid":15828,"level":30,"msg":"Active directory search (cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal) for \"(&(objectCategory=User)(distinguishedName=cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal))\" returned 0 entries.","time":"2019-12-03T06:09:33.207Z","v":0}
{"name":"ldapApp","hostname":"DESKTOP-K4GOMAF","pid":15828,"level":40,"msg":"User \"cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal\" not found for query \"(&(objectCategory=User)(distinguishedName=cn=akshay,cn=testContainer,cn=admin,dc=ec2,dc=internal))\"","time":"2019-12-03T06:09:33.208Z","v":0}
User: not found.
```

Am not able to figure out what is going wrong here..

Comment: This should probably be added to your question rather than be an answer. (but it is helpful!)